# Can I have a CMSPluginBase class method directly return a custom plugin's html?

Tags: django, django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I would like to create a Django CMS plugin primarily used as a child of a TextPlugin (`djangocms-text-ckeditor`). It is meant to return a link to an application page.

To this end I subclass CMSPluginBase as described in the doc. It seems that the CMSPluginBase is relying on each plugin to have its own template.

Do I have to have a `template.html` file or can I write a method for the CMSPluginBase subclass that directly returns the rendered html (essentially something really simple like `'<a href="/some/page">App link</a>'`) and avoid the invocation of a template to be rendered?

Thanks very much for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

It seems that the `render_template` does not have to be a string. It can be a `django.template.Template` instance, too. So, here we go:

```
from django.template import Template

class MyLinkPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    render_template = Template('<a href="{{link}}">{{anchor}}</a>')
    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context['link']='http://google.com'
        context['anchor'] = 'Google me'
        return(context)
```